# Getting Default Adapter Failed error for Selenium Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I had created this selenium bot to do some task on a website. It was working fine till last week, but suddenly I started seeing errors in the console (screenshot attached). But it doesn't end the program.

The bot doesn't use Bluetooth. It is simple bot that fills a form and then submits.

Has anyone seen this error before? I would really appreciate if someone could advise me on how to resolve this.

Edited: I wasn't able to find any solution for this. Hence, I changed webdriver to Firefox.

P.S. My chrome browser version is 81.0.4044.138, which is compatible with chrome webdriver that I downloaded.

[image: Adapter Error image]

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. The error does not always show up, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. Hence it is difficult to reproduce or guess when this error will come. Also, the code hasn't been changed, it was working fine till last week. The error is coming from Chrome webdriver, which I have already attached. I did some research and I didn't find much about this error on Google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve 'Getting Default Adapter failed' error when launching Chrome and try to access a webpage using the ChromeDriver using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561112/how-to-solve-getting-default-adapter-failed-error-when-launching-chrome-and-tr)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the answer to this question- [How to solve 'Getting Default Adapter failed' error when launching Chrome and try to access a webpage using the ChromeDriver using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561112/how-to-solve-getting-default-adapter-failed-error-when-launching-chrome-and-tr), you should check that-

- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels *Version 3.141.59*. You can check that using the following python command:

  ```
   import selenium
   print(selenium.__version__)
  ```

  ---

  ```
   >>> 3.141.0
  ```
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to current *ChromeDriver v84.0* level. You can check it using following CLI command:

  ```
  chromedriver -v
  ```

  ---

  ```
  > ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87
  ```
- *Chrome* is updated to current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per *ChromeDriver v84.0* release notes)

  Check your chrome version from the browser settings, on left pane click About Chrome in the bottom.

  [image]
- If your base Web Client version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of Web Client.