# Automated Chrome Extension installation fails on jenkins windows node

Tags: windows, jenkins, google-chrome-extension

In my Jenkins job I try to install a chrome-extension using

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension="D:\Jenkins\workspace\test\chome_installation\chromeupload" --no-first-run`

but the installation always get stuck

```
6592:13760:0513/113631.656:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:36:31.656] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

If I do this directly on the machine from cmd it works fine.

Any idea of the root cause of the issue and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that can be solved by taking a number of steps. Since this isn't a real error, the easiest thing to do is to suppress this error. This [article](http://blogs.stevelongchen.com/2020/05/15/selenium-chrome-driver-resolve-error-messages-regarding-registry-keys-and-experimental-options/) gives all the necessary information on how to do this. Basically, you add

```
excludeSwitches: ['enable-logging']
```

Into your chrome options. There is detailed analysis of the problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270005/3730626).

You could also try updaing Selenium, Chrome, and the ChromeDriver used. The command might work when you run it on the machine from cmd since it doesn't use Selenium or ChromeDriver when you do that. So the reason it gives this error when using Jenkins should be related to either of the two.